# Visualforce page extended tab issue in screen

Tags: visualforce

As the screen shot depicts when we try loading the visualforce page ,tabs are not getting wrapped and gets streched horizontally.What is the reason behind this issue?How can it be rectified?

[image]

Comment: It's probably worth sharing your Visualforce Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face this issue earlier. I think you are using `window.onload` in your code. You need to remove that to solve this problem.

You can use `$( document ).ready()`  of Jquery
 or can call the method before `Apex:page` closing tag.

```
javascriptFun();
```